# Automatically run kpartx during boot after 2022

Tags: ubuntu, udev, startup, kpartx

I'm trying to detect and run partitions on top of jMicron fakeRAID, which is discovered by dmraid. How far I'm stuck with making this automatically during boot.

```bash
hopungo@hopungo-pc:~$ sudo kpartx -l /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 
jmicron_GRAID1 : 0 7813722112 /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 2048
```

Here is a [good known solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65746/automatically-run-kpartx-during-boot) from year 2010, but it is outdated in 2023 (probably, after 22.04). You simply will not find `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-kpartx.rules`. And if you make your own, it doesn't work.

Another option is to use `rc.local` script, but it doesn't work too and also looks  a bit crutchy. Is there any canonical way to run `kpartx` on start since 22.04?